# how to get the best solution as a column from genetic algorithm (genalg)

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I am using genalg package for Genetic Algorithm. The gene is binary is nature and the result will specify

The length of the gene is 269 and it is difficult to understand which is difficult to comprehend. Is there a way to extract the result from this and have it in a data frame?

```
cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel))

GA Settings
Type                  = binary chromosome
Population size       = 100
Number of Generations = 100
Elitism               = TRUE
Mutation Chance       = 0

Search Domain
Var 1 = [,]
Var 0 = [,]

GA Results
Best Solution : 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

I want to convert the Best Solution to a data frame, so that I can actually look up which are the items that I need to pick.

```
class(GAmodel) = "rbga"
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (an example from the function's help page works, too)?

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/ - Here there is a example where the gene size is small and the author manually creates the result vector, since the size is small

Comment: Please integrate this into your question. The site may disappear without notice and then your question is not as well rounded as it could be.

Answer (score 6):

For a minimization optimization solved to variable GAModel

```
bestSolution<-GAmodel$population[which.min(GAmodel$evaluations),]
```

This pulls the index of the best chromosome from GAmodel$evaluations, based on the fitness function.  Using the index, it then returns the full chromosome from the last population which was evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's certainly an issue with the output of genalg, here's how I managed to extract the best solution:

- summar<-(summary.rbga(my_model))
- summar<-strsplit(summar,"\n")[[1]]
- summar<-strsplit(summar[13]," ")[[1]]
- summar<-as.numeric(summar[-(1:5)])